# How to convert hex data to UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, bitmap, uiimage

I like to display .cpbitmap (its the file formate iOS saves the wallpapers) in a UIImageView. The problem is I need to convert it. I already figure out that if you get its Data (NSData) and convert every bit you get the UIColor, so the first Bit is R, then B, then G and then Alpha (I think). Now I need to "draw" an UIImage out of the info. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the link to the .cpbitmap file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9v4lahixm9cuql/LockBackground.cpbitmap

It would be really cool if someone can help me,

Thanks

***EDIT***
I found a working python script, is someone able to translate it to Objective

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image,ImageOps
import struct
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Need two args: filename and result_filename\n";
    sys.exit(0)
filename = sys.argv[1]
result_filename = sys.argv[2]

with open(filename) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    unk1, width, height, unk2, unk3, unk4 = struct.unpack('<6i', contents[-24:])
    im = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (width,height), contents, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
    r,g,b,a = im.split()
    im = Image.merge('RGBA', (b,g,r,a))
    im.save(result_filename)
```

Comment: How you recognize image's resolution? Is it predefined?

Comment: Do you mean the height and with? Its the same height and with of the device.

Comment: I was first confused by the non-standard image dimensions, but I guess that because of the parallax effect rendered by `UIMotionEffect`, the dimensions will be larger than the physical device dimensions (so that as the image shifts, there's stuff to show). Having empirically discovered that the size was 744x1392, I notice that at the end of the file, I can see those dimensions, `0x2E8` (744) and `0x570` (1392), encoded in there. I'm unsure how you would programmatically extract that data. (It's not a `NSKeyedArchiver`, which I generally associate with `bplist`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic process of converting RGBA data into an image is to create a `CGDataProviderRef` with the raw data, and then use `CGImageCreate` to create a `CGImageRef`, from which you can easily generate a `UIImage`. So, that gives you something like:

```
- (UIImage *) imageForBitmapData:(NSData *)data size:(CGSize)size
{
    void *          bitmapData;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace        = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4);
    int             bitmapByteCount   = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);

    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    NSAssert(bitmapData, @"Unable to create buffer");

    [data getBytes:bitmapData length:bitmapByteCount];

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, bitmapData, bitmapByteCount, releasePixels);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(size.width,
                                        size.height,
                                        8,
                                        32,
                                        bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                        colorSpace,
                                        (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaLast,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        NO,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    return image;
}
```

With a `releasePixels` function defined as follows:

```
void releasePixels(void *info, const void *data, size_t size)
{
    free((void*)data);
}
```

The only trick was identifying the dimensions of the bitmap. There are 4,142,592 bytes of image data (there is some extra stuff at the end of the file, which is self evident if you examine the file in hexadecimal in Xcode). That doesn't correlate to any standard device dimensions. But if you look at the possible values that divide evenly into 4,142,592, you get a couple of promising ones (496, 522, 558, 576, 696, 744, 899, 928, and 992). And if you just try those out, it becomes obvious that the image is 744 x 1392.

You can then use those dimensions with the above method, and you get your image.

---

While I discovered the size of the image empirically, I noticed that those dimensions were encoded at the end of the file. This is confirmed by your Python code, which suggests that the image width is the fifth from the last `UInt32`, and the height is the fourth from the last `UInt32`. Thus, you can use the above routine like so, extracting the dimensions from those two 32-bit integers encoded near the end of the file:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LockBackground" ofType:@"cpbitmap"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSAssert(data, @"no data found");

UInt32 width;
UInt32 height;
[data getBytes:&width  range:NSMakeRange([data length] - sizeof(UInt32) * 5, sizeof(UInt32))];
[data getBytes:&height range:NSMakeRange([data length] - sizeof(UInt32) * 4, sizeof(UInt32))];

self.imageView.image = [self imageForBitmapData:data size:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

Comment: Hi, your code isn't really working for me. And why do I need the height and width of the image? The python tool can do it without knowing the height and width.

Comment: Ok, I now have an interesting issue for you. It only works on the iOS simulator, not on real iOS Devices, do you have any idea why, cause I don't have a single idea. The file is readable (Its in the devices document directory for now and its the same as the one from the simulator). did you test it on the iOS simulator or on a real iOS device?

Comment: I kind of fixed it. Everything works fine if you remove 'free(bitmapData);'

Comment: @DavidG. My bad. I tried to simplify my example by removing the `releasePixels` clean up function and freeing the memory immediately (on the assumption that `imageWithCGImage` would copy the image data). That was a bad idea, and I've reverted back to the rendition that uses that last parameter to `CGDataProviderCreateWithData`. Note, if you just remove the `free()`, without something like this `releasePixels` function, your app will leak. Anyways, the revised code works on both simulator and device.

Comment: ok, I updated my code. Now I am wondering if there is a way to do the whole thing vice versa. I am already did some thinking, but I wasn't able to come up with an good idea.

Comment: Converting a UIImage to a .cpbitmap File

Comment: @DavidG. Getting the pixel buffer is not hard (get the `CGImage` from the `UIImage`, use `CGImageGetDataProvider` to get the data provider, use that to get the pixel buffer (see [QA1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html)). (If the image wasn't RGBA, though, some manipulation might be needed, though). Nor would it be hard to adding the last 24 bytes, including the width and height. The problem might be, though, that there is some curious `bplist` and other data after the image data and before those last 24 bytes, and I don't know if that's needed or not.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift You can use this extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(hexString: String) {
        let stringArray = Array(hexString)
        var data = Data(capacity: stringArray.count / 2)
        
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: stringArray.count, by: 2) {
            let byteString = String(stringArray[i...i+1])
            if var byte = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16) {
                data.append(&byte, count: 1)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        self.init(data: data)
    }
}
```

and then, you can call the init method like this:

```
let hexString = "sadsydasdyadgdbdd"
let img = UIImage((hexString: hexString))
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: It has indeed! the question is how to convert hex Data to UIImage, and that convenience Init does that!!

Comment: No. The question has nothing to do with converting a string into an image. And your sample code makes no sense. How is a string with characters other than 0-9 and a-f a hex string? Also, note that the accepted answer doesn't do anything with strings. And the question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift.